# How does nmap calculate the difficulty of TCP sequence prediction?

Tags: networking, nmap

I am learning how nmap operates by testing it with another workstation in my network.  When I entered

```
nmap -v -A -sS 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Part of the output produced the line below.

```
TCP Sequence Prediction: Difficulty=260 (Good luck!)
```

How is 260 calculated and what makes it difficult to predict the next sequence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The topic of TCP sequence prediction is covered pretty well in the online Nmap book's [OS detection page](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html) under "TCP Sequence Prediction." Essentially, statistical methods such as the Greatest Common Denominator (GCD) are used to predict the sequence's variability. There is more discussion on the [OS detection methods page](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-methods.html#osdetect-gcd), and you can look at the code in [osscan2.cc](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/osscan2.cc#L2248) in the `HostOsScan::makeTSeqFP` function.